# Laravel Image Library relationship

Tags: php, laravel, database-design, polymorphic-associations, laravel-relations

let me describe the scenario first:

We need an Image model which holds all images of that project, like,

```
Country has `single` image and `multiple images` for gallery,

Store has `single` image, logo and `multiple images` for gallery,

... and so on
```

I tried `classic-o/nova-media-library`, `spatie/laravel-medialibrary` and trust me, these works like charm... But we need to make it simple, light-weight and don't want to use unnecessary dependencies, so,

We make an Image model based on Polymorphic Many-to-many relationship.

Now the problem is that, we dont know how to use this for single image columns, like, `country image, store image and logo, ...`

CURRENT STATUS:
Currently we're using `type` field with `filter` inside model to identify the image type

Sorry for any typo & grammar mistakes...

Regards

Comment: You can define `type` column on polymorphic table. It can be use to define type of image: logo, store image etc.

Comment: @Daniel we already planned to do this, if didn't get any appropriate options